# I can't find where i forgot to use comma in mapper of Spring

Tags: sql, spring, oracle

[image]

I tried to fix my root causes but I can't find where is problem.

Console says i forgot comma, but I don't know well where is this

```
### SQL: INSERT INTO TEST_MEMBER1 (     MEMBER_ID     , MEMBER_PASSWORD     , MEMBER_NAME     , MEMBER_AGE     , MEMBER_ADDR    , TO_CHAR(MEMBER_BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS BIRTHDAY_DATE    )     VALUES(     ?     , ?     , ?     , ?     , ?     ,?    )
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: 누락된 콤마

; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: 누락된 콤마
]을(를) 발생시켰습니다.
Error : 917, Position : 128, Sql = INSERT INTO TEST_MEMBER1 (
            MEMBER_ID
            , MEMBER_PASSWORD
            , MEMBER_NAME
            , MEMBER_AGE
            , MEMBER_ADDR
            , TO_CHAR(MEMBER_BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS BIRTHDAY_DATE
        ) 
        VALUES(
            :1 
            , :2 
            , :3 
            , :4 
            , :5 
            ,:6 
        ), OriginalSql = INSERT INTO TEST_MEMBER1 (
            MEMBER_ID
            , MEMBER_PASSWORD
            , MEMBER_NAME
            , MEMBER_AGE
            , MEMBER_ADDR
            , TO_CHAR(MEMBER_BIRTHDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS BIRTHDAY_DATE
        ) 
        VALUES(
            ?
            , ?
            , ?
            , ?
            , ?
            ,?
        ), Error Msg = ORA-00917: 누락된 콤마
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a `to_char()` function call in the column list; it should be in the values clause instead:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_MEMBER1 (
            MEMBER_ID
            , MEMBER_PASSWORD
            , MEMBER_NAME
            , MEMBER_AGE
            , MEMBER_ADDR
            , MEMBER_BIRTHDATE
        ) 
        VALUES(
            ?
            , ?
            , ?
            , ?
            , ?
            , TO_CHAR(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        )
```

But that conversion implies that your `MEMBER_BIRTHDATE` is a string (VARCHAR2) column. You should store data in columns with the correct data type, so really that should be a DATE column, and then when you bind a date value it won't need to be converted.